# Prove that $\| f \| := \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)|$ is a norm on the vector space $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ be the set of all continuous functions $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$.
>   Prove that $\| f \| := \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)|$ is a norm on the vector space $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$.

I know a norm has to satisfy the three conditions

1. $\| x \| = 0 \iff x = 0$
2. $\| a x \| = |a| \| x \| \ \forall a \in \mathbb{R}, x \in \mathbb{R}^m$
3. The triangle inequality

For this function, I am confused as to how to satisfy conditions 1 and 3

For condition 1 , how do I prove max |f(x)| = 0 iff the function equals zero?

For condition 3, I think we start with $\| f_1 + f_2 \| \le \| f_1 \| + \| f_2 \|$ but don't know where to go from there.

Comment: A sketch for part 3: consider the point where $|f_1+f_2|$ attains its maximum. If both $|f_1|$ and $|f_2|$ attain their maximum there, then you have equality and are done. If not, then one or both of them is smaller than their maximum value at the maximum of $|f_1+f_2|$, which gives the strict inequality.

Answer (score 4):

For condition $(1)$ it is clear that $\|f\| \geq 0$ for all $f$. And: $$\|f\| = \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)| = 0 \implies |f(x)| = 0,\quad\forall\,x\in[0,1]\implies f(x) = 0,\quad\forall\,x\in[0,1].$$ For $(3)$, you take the supremum in the right order: $$|f(x)+g(x)|\leq |f(x)|+|g(x)| \leq \|f\|+\|g\|,\quad \forall\,x\in[0,1]\implies \|f+g\|\leq\|f\|+\|g\|.$$

Comment: For (2): $$|a|\,\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)| = \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|a\,f(x)|, \quad\forall a\in \mathbb{R}.$$